# AudioHardwareALSA errors with Android AudioRecord

Tags: android, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

I'm starting a simple AudioRecord app that I am writing and it starts with a bunch of these:

```
12-19 17:05:57.393: WARN/ResourceType(2233): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f0800f4
```

and then this:

```
12-19 17:05:57.863: ERROR/AudioHardwareALSA(2182): AudioStreamInALSA::AudioStreamInALSA mMode=-1
12-19 17:05:57.863: ERROR/AudioHardwareALSA(2182): AudioStreamInALSA - input   - format = 1, channels = 16, rate = 44100
12-19 17:05:57.863: ERROR/AudioHardwareALSA(2182): AudioStreamInALSA - default - format = 1, channels = 16, rate = 44100
12-19 17:05:57.863: ERROR/AudioHardwareALSA(2182): AudioStreamInALSA - mDefaults->sampleRate = 44100
12-19 17:05:57.963: ERROR/AudioFlinger(2182): readInputParameters mInputBytes 8320, mFrameSize 2 mSampleRate 44100 mChannelCount(1)
12-19 17:05:57.963: ERROR/(2182): AFCCreateReSampler: avAFCInfo->bUsed[0] inSampleRate[44100] outSampleRate[44100] nChannel[1] outbitDepth[16]
12-19 17:05:58.278: WARN/AudioFlinger(2182): RecordThread: buffer overflow
12-19 17:05:58.328: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(6726): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-19 17:06:05.598: ERROR/ALSALib(2182): external/alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:7231:(snd_pcm_recover) overrun occured
```

What might this mean?  I can post source code if necessary, but I'm looking for a basic answer of what these errors might refer to and why a buffer overflow might occur in such a situation.  Thanks.

Comment: +1, would like to know the answer to this

Comment: @Tom the first errors "WARN/ResourceType... etc." are inconsequential.  Buffer overflow occurs with the AudioRecord object when the audio buffer gets filled and is not read quickly enough.  When the buffer fills up and is not read from, it needs to discard threads and it throws these buffer overflow errors to alert the developer that there you missed some samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error "overrun occurred".   Read this:

http://lxr.post-tech.com/source/external/alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm.c and within the remark it explained:

266 This error means xrun (underrun for playback or overrun for capture).
267 The underrun can happen when an application does not feed new samples
268 in time to alsa-lib (due CPU usage). The overrun can happen when
269 an application does not take new captured samples in time from alsa-lib.
270

so it simply means the capturing thread is too busy doing other things - is that correct?   Perhaps u should create a thread dedicated to capturing the audio stream?

But reading this:

http://programming-android.labs.oreilly.com/ch14.html

it could also be due to insufficient buffer allocated for capturing.   Is that correct?